# How to automate youtube using selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I just tried to automate 'downloading a youtube video' using selenium web driver. But it isn't working. Here, I'm just opening a youtube video and copying its URL. And then I'm pasting that URL in 'SaveItOffline' tab on another page and clicking download. But the URL is not get copied. Here is my code,

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;`enter code here`
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
public class Download {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/vairavan/Desktop/SELENIUM/chrome driver/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.youtube.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("search")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("search")).sendKeys("short flute cover");
    driver.findElement(By.id("search")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    driver.findElement(By.id("dismissable")).click();
    Actions action=new Actions(driver);
    action.contextClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ytd-player/div/div[1]/video"))).perform();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]")).click();
    driver.get("htttp://www.saveitoffline.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("url-input")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"v");
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit-url")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("download-href")).click();

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Clipboard to paste the url, It works to me:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
String data = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
webDriver.findElement(By.id("url-input")).sendKeys(data);
```